# Is their is another library in Android that provides same functionality as OpenCV Library - 2.4.7

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, camera

I just **need to calculate frame difference and threashodign** of given frame. I am **currently using OpenCV** Library so am getting camera frame in bellow method but i don't want to user OpenCV **is any any another library can give** the frame difference and image threasholding functionality

My Current Code which written in  **android with OpenCV Library 2.4.7**

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrames) {
      Mat rgba=inputFrames.rgba();
      Mat inputFrame=inputFrames.gray(); 
  inputFrame.copyTo(current);
  if(first){//first is true at the first time
        inputFrame.copyTo(previous);
        first = false;
        Log.i("First processing", "Pierwszy przebieg");
    }
  Core.absdiff(current, previous, difference);
  inputFrame.copyTo(previous);
  inputFrame=null;
  Mat closed = new Mat();
  Imgproc.threshold(difference, closed, -1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
  return closed;
}
```

I need to another **library which performs Frame Difference and Threasholding on byte[] array**
*I need any code,function,class or any other Library can do this task*

```
       public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] paramAnonymousArrayOfByte, Camera paramAnonymousCamera)  
        { 
                // Frame difference and threasholding code goes here

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If needing a result as a byte array is the only reason for not wanting to use OpenCV, [you can convert a Mat to a byte array with the put method](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html):

```
someMat.put(0, 0, byteArray);
```

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html